What causes this child sizing difference between flexbox and default block?
I noticed a behavior difference between default display type and flexbox, and I don't understand what is causing it. Here's a minimal example code I came up with:


body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<video controls></video>



In this example the video seems to be slightly higher than the screen - the vertical scrollbar is visible and it's possible to scroll for a small amount.
Adding display: flex to body changes this. Now the video perfectly fills the screen and there's no scrollbars.
So. Why does this happen?

Why does flexbox make the scrollbars disappear
Why are there even scrollbars in the first place?


Some more details, in the order of decreasing probable importance:
I thought that this behavior is related to box-sizing, but that's probably not it: replacing video with bordered div also causes the scrollbars to appear (as expected), but then flexbox does not make them disappear. Also, adding box-sizing: border-box to video does not make scrollbars disappear.
If viewed in the debugger, there doesn't seem to be any actual size difference in any elements between the flexbox and no-flexbox cases. It seems to be purely visual (at least in firefox)
flex-direction does not matter - both row and column make scrollbars disappear.
As far as I can tell, this behavior is not specific to video. In fact, I first encountered it in some other case. I could't reproduce that in a simple way though, so video it is. Video controls are not necessary to reproduce the behavior, but they make it easier to see.
Checked in firefox and chromium - reproduces in both.

The size difference seems to only be in the vertical direction. The width is perfectly filled in both flexbox and no-flexbox cases. Edited the question to clarify

Ah, it's the classic "whitespace below replaced inline elements" problem. The video sits on the baseline - full explanation, see duplicate. Applying display:block to it will therefor also fix the issue.

Yep. That fixes it. Thanks

To more directly answer my first question (why flexbox makes the scrollbar disappear): As far a I inderstood, flexbox automatically changes display-type of its children, so in this case a video inside a flexbox is no longer inline

Yes, that is of course also correct. The underlaying issue is the behavior of inline elements, but there's several different ways of "disabling" that.
